# Echo PHP variable from another script

Tags: php

I have 2 PHP documents; my main index.php and my data.php which gets some info from a database and puts it into variables. How would I echo some variables from the data.php in the index.php?

Comment: use `session` or `get/post` the data from one page to another

Comment: @SteamPunk_Devil Are you executing index.php? - I guess. Then include data.php in index.php document and set some variables. And just print them in index.php.

Comment: @SteamPunk_Devil put some more details please in case I did not get you.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia How would I execute data.php from index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SteamPunk_Devil

Suppose below is your index.php file:

```
<?php

    // This is index.php

    // Your initial code .....

    require 'data.php'; // in data.php set some variables, arrays etc.

    // Now you can print the variables, arrays from data.php file in index.php    

?>
```

Let me know if this does not make sense.

Comment: @SteamPunk_Devil Also check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what  I wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you want really different files. You have to save your data in a session or in your database.

Or otherway if you redirect from one to another send your data over `GET` or `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` keyword in front of the variable you want to use, in the file you wish to use it to tell your files that something should be available in all your files, so long as the file is being included.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use `include()` ,`require_once()` or `require()` for include `data.php` in `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php

```
$variable = 'value';//Initialize before including

require_once "data.php";
```

In the data.php

```
echo $variable;
```

A better approach is having a file containing all variable initializations which are needed in all the files in the script execution and then requiring this file before the files which are going to use the variables

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to make function that obtain  data in `data.php`, and include this file to `index.php` with executing this function, f.e.:

**file data.php:**

```
 <?php
        function getData()
        {
            return 'data';
        }
```

**file index.php:**

```
<?php
    require_once 'data.php';
    $data = getData();
    echo $data;
```